# SQL Server PIVOT table for Hours

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, pivot

I have a T-SQL query as below which queries a table holding the search data and gets the search hour and count of the rows for that search hour.

```
SELECT DATEPART(HOUR, aps.CreatedOn) AS SearchHour, COUNT(*) AS ItemCOUNT 
FROM ASearches aps
GROUP BY DATEPART(HOUR, aps.CreatedOn)
ORDER BY SearchHour;
```

As you can see, this does't produce a great result. However, I know that if I use a Pivot table for this and have the hours as column names, that would be better. I tried but I have been failing so far.

Any idea how?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Something like this:

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT DATEPART(HOUR, CreatedOn) AS SearchHour 
          FROM ASearches) aps
 PIVOT (COUNT([SearchHour]) FOR SearchHour IN 
         ( [0],  [1],  [2],  [3],  [4],  [5], 
           [6],  [7],  [8],  [9], [10], [11], 
          [12], [13], [14], [15], [16], [17], 
          [18], [19], [20], [21], [22], [23])) as pvt
```

Comment: ah, very nice. There was one mistake, I corrected it. Thanks!

Comment: Ahh yeah, sorry - I made it work on a DB I had and then edited back in your original names - incorrectly :) Thanks